Upgrading my Kubuntu bricks the GUI
I have a Kubuntu 22.04.4, kernel 5.15.105, and GPU Nvidia GTX 1650. When I upgraded my system with the command
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y

It has upgraded the kernel to 5.15.107. When I try to start the system, the Nvidia displays an error message: "failed to start NVIDIA - persistence daemon". Trying nvidia-xconfig says that it is unable to locate or edit /etc/X11. Doing ls /etc/X* indeed shows that there's no such directory with that name.
I am writing all of this from memory since I can't just copy paste it to a browser so pardon the inaccuracy
Looking at this issue for past versions, it seemed that the problem was related to secure boot. I don't think that is the case for this one, as everything works just fine with the older kernel.

Can you not on boot select other options and load the last kernel?

I can, my issue is that I can't upgrade the kernel at all like this. Choosing the older version is a temporary solution

How did you install the nVidia drivers? I ask because if you used the official Ubuntu packages in the repositories they should be updated automatically. If you didn't, for instance if you downloaded them from nVidia itself, then remove them, reboot, and finally add the drivers from Ubuntu itself.
https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation

@LiamProven, I use the default drivers. I never installed them manually

That's not enough info go on. I suggest you follow the steps in the link I gave.
